# Retrieve Nuget Package Manager file in my java program (IntelliJ)

Tags: intellij-idea, nuget-package

I got a dll file with an extension .nupkg from my .Net developer team mate which I need to use in my java program. How do I go about it? I use intellij.

Answer (score 0):

A nupkg is just a zip file so you should be able to unzip it and see what it contains.

You can also take a look at the JNI (Java Native Interface, google or Wikipedia can tell you more), which lets you call out from Java to other languages. This isn't trivial though.